# Did Ramban consider marital relations sinful?

Tags: talmud-gemara, ramban, marital-relations, purity, young-men

Bavli Berachos 43b states as follows:

> וְאָמַר רַב זוּטְרָא בַּר טוֹבִיָּה אָמַר רַב: עֲתִידִים בַּחוּרֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁיִּתְּנוּ רֵיחַ טוֹב כַּלְּבָנוֹן. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: {הושע י"ד:ז'} "יֵלְכוּ יוֹנְקוֹתָיו וִיהִי כַזַּיִת הוֹדוֹ וְרֵיחַ לוֹ כַּלְּבָנוֹן".
>
> And Rav Zutra bar Toviya said that Rav said: The young men of Israel are destined to emit a sweet scent as the Lebanon, as it is stated: “His branches shall spread and his beauty will be as the olive tree, and his fragrance as Lebanon” (Hosea 14:7).

Ramban, in explanation of [Shemos 24:5](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ramban/Shemot/24.5#m4e0n6), quotes the gemara but possessed a few extra words and explains them as referring to young men who have never engaged in intimate relations:

> ועל דרך הפשט נערי בני ישראל הם בחורי ישראל שלא טעמו טעם חטא, שלא נגשו אל אשה מעולם, כי הם הנבחרים בעם והקדושים בהם, כענין שאמרו (בבלי ברכות מ"ג:) עתידין בחורי ישראל שלא טעמו טעם חטא ליתן ריח כלבנון וכו'.
>
> In line with the plain meaning of Scripture, the young men of the children of Israel were the youth of Israel who had not tasted of sin, and had never come near a woman, for they were the most select and holy of the people, in a similar manner to that which the Rabbis have said: "The young men of Israel who have not tasted of sin are destined to give forth a fragrance like the Lebanon etc."

Ramban seems to indicate that all intimate relations mar a person's purity—even within the context of marriage.

Did Ramban read into the Talmud the idea that even marital relations are sinful?

Comment: See the link, as yes this appears to be his opinion  https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Leviticus.18.6.1

Comment: @אילפא Holding that something should be minimized doesn't seem to be the same as saying that it is sinful behavior

Comment: Sinful is the wrong word - to the contrary marriage is a mitzvah. But it does "mar their purity" as you put it

Comment: @AKA His girsa in the gemara is שלא טעמו טעם חטא

Comment: @nahum - agreed, but the understanding of that is clearly not that celibacy is preferred, but rather that marriage is a lesser evil

Comment: Maybe he means something like https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.164b.16